# How to access nested JSON in Apex?

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

I'm new to Apex and I would appreciate some help with the following:

The code below returns the entire list from input:

```java
public static string input ='[{"item1": 1,"item2": "2","item3": [{"child1": "11","child2": "22","child3": 33}]},{"item1": "aa","item2": "bb","item3": [{"child1": "22","child2": "33","child3": 12}]}]';

List<Object> jsonParsed = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(input);
System.debug(jsonParsed);
```

and I want to get the child of "item3", so that I can read:

> "item1": "1" "child1": "11" "child2": "22" "child3": 33

I have tried the code below without success, and I get item1 but null for child 1,2 and 3.

```java
for(Object jsonParsed : jsonParsed){
        Map<String,Object> ind = (Map<String,Object> )jsonParsed;
        System.debug('item1 = '+ ind.get('item1'));        
        System.debug('child1 = '+ ind.get('item3.child1[0]'));
        System.debug('child2 = '+ ind.get('item3.child2[1]'));
        System.debug('child3 = '+ ind.get('item3.child3[2]'));
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"? What happened?

Comment: thanks."without success" meaning that i was not able to get the expected results

Comment: What did you get instead?

Comment: I just modified my post to give more details about what I got instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apex does not support relationship paths or expressions in the `get()` method like this:

```
    System.debug('child1 = '+ ind.get('item3.child1[0]'));
```

That will simply return `null`.

You must access each level of structure in the JSON in sequence, and if you are using `deserializeUntyped()` you must also cast data structures at each level (because `get()` returns the generic type `Object`):

```
    Map<String, Object> item3 = (Map<String, Object>)ind.get('item3');
    List<Object> child1 = (Map<String, Object>)item3.get('child1');
    Object child1Item = child1[0];

    System.debug('child1 = ' + child1Item);
```

It's generally much easier, where possible, to define a strongly-typed Apex class representing your JSON and deserialize into that. Your JSON is generic enough here that I don't see how to do that; you would need to look at the actual data types and keys and consider using a tool like [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Thank you David but I tried the sugested code and I get the followin error code: Illegal assignment from Map<String,Object> to List<Object>
Would you mind to ellabotrate?

Comment: @Jav I was looking at your code and didn't notice that it doesn't currently match your JSON. Please take this code as a general suggestion or pattern. You actually have several nested lists in your JSON that you need to index through as additional layers of structure. I really do recommend if at all possible going the route of typed deserialization.